# Raspberry pi 1 model b+: External hard drives stop working

Tags: hard-drive, pi-b+

I have a raspberry pi 1 model b+.
I try to use my hard drives with it however, usually after several minutes of writing/reading the hard drives suddenly stop working. And they won't work until I reboot the pi.(I am unable to unmount and remount them)

One of the drives is a USB2.0 hard drive with a USB Y cable. The other one is a USB3.0 hard drive. I have tried using just one of them at a time as well.
I use a usb hub with an external power supply for the drives. It says it supports a 5V 2A output.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Do the drives keep spinning when this happens? Any relevant `dmesg` messages?

Comment: The drives don't spin, in fact sometimes I hear them abruptly shutting down. The drives work perfectly on my laptop though.

Comment: I haven't yet tried dmesg.